Angular content projection using ng-content only working on root level?
I'm trying to select elements in ng-content, but seems to work only if the element is on content's root level
root component
<app-wrapper>
<div class="root">Test1</div>
<div>
<div class="sub">Test2</div>
</div>
</app-wrapper>

child component - works as expected
<ng-content select=".root"></ng-content>

child component - no content selected
<ng-content select=".sub"></ng-content>


Yes this is a limitation of content projection.
Only 1st level children are matched for content projection.

hm, is it mentioned in the angular docs somewhere?

Not specifically, but you'll find many issues around that topic on the angular repo.
